# Ionic Working Directory is Not a Cordova-based Project

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am running both - latest version of Cordova and I am inside of the projects, yet I receive the message when I try to create another project or just perform - @ionic build android.

Any solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Anyone who has any idea?

Additional to that, I did uninstalled cordova, did it in my specific folder in order to be up-to-date.

Comment: What's your setup environment? Windows, Mac? Maybe these links can help you https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/2213 and https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1624

Comment: It was fixed, I am dexteriti from the second link. However the error is very common.